# Using cross validation to decrease variation in prediction outcomes

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

Im trying to predict the won category of some soccer matches. I have the following df:

```
head(df)
won               TEAM1              TEAM2  EXPG1   EXPG2 VAR1  VAR2
41   1            Bordeaux             Bastia 1.4200 0.93285  0.33  0.32
42   0                Caen             Rennes 1.3105 1.11580  0.44  0.43
43   2                Lens              Reims 1.3678 0.90433  0.34  0.43
44   2             Lorient           Guingamp 1.1773 0.96671  0.43  0.54
45   2 Olympique Marseille               Nice 1.3541 0.89154  0.53  0.54
46   2                Metz Olympique Lyonnais 1.1768 0.99026  0.53  0.61
```

No I would like to the following:

- Test whether my prediction gets better if I include VAR1 OR VAR2 besides EXPG1 and EXPG2
- (If my prediction get bettter) - test whether OR VAR1 or VAR2 should be included (which var gets a better accuracy.

I did the following

```
#library(caret)
inTrain <- createDataPartition(y=df$won, p=0.7, list=FALSE)
training <- df[inTrain, ]
testing <- df[-inTrain, ]

#perform rf for EXPG1 and EXPG2
fit1 <- randomForest(won ~ EXPG1 + EXPG2, data=training, importance=TRUE, ntree=2000) 
Prediction1 <- predict(fit1, testing)
conf1 <- confusionMatrix(Prediction, testing$won)
#get accuracy

   #perform rf for EXPG1, EXPG2 and VAR1
fit1 <- randomForest(won ~ EXPG1 + EXPG2 + VAR1 , data=training, importance=TRUE, ntree=2000) 
Prediction1 <- predict(fit1, testing)
conf1 <- confusionMatrix(Prediction, testing$won)
#get accuracy


#perform rf for EXPG1, EXPG2 and VAR1
fit1 <- randomForest(won ~ EXPG1 + EXPG2 + VAR2 , data=training, importance=TRUE, ntree=2000) 
Prediction1 <- predict(fit1, testing)
conf1 <- confusionMatrix(Prediction, testing$won)
#get accuracy
```

To get an overview of whether VAR1/VAR2 have impact and which factor might have better impact.

Im not sure whether this is the right approach however because when I run this statement twice (WITHOUT setting seed):

```
     #perform rf for EXPG1 and EXPG2
fit1 <- randomForest(won ~ EXPG1 + EXPG2, data=training, importance=TRUE, ntree=2000) 
Prediction1 <- predict(fit1, testing)
conf1 <- confusionMatrix(Prediction, testing$won)
#get accuracy
```

I get two different accuracy values (41% en 43%).

So if im getting the result that adding VAR1 increases the accuracy by 1% that might be due to chance (as running the algoritm twice with only EXPG1 and EXPG2 can already differ 2%).

Any thoughts on how I can do a solid test to see what the added value of VAR1 and VAR2 might be?

Comment: With or without Paris Saint Germain?

Comment: Shouldn't you fit randomForest on `train`, not on entire `df` which contains `testing`? CV doesn't imply in any way that you should expose the model to the test data during training.

Comment: @cyberj0g thanks for your reply. So fit <- train(won ~ EXPG1 + EXPG2, data=training, trControl=train_control, method="rf") would do the trick?

Comment: Yes. What do you mean by `predictions still diff`? 2% of difference in accuracy between CV and test results is actually pretty good.

Comment: No I mean that one time I get an accuracy of 41% and if I run it another time (without setting seed) it gives me 43% ...

Comment: The question is unclear. Do you mean differencies between two runs of the same piece of code or runs of two different pieces of code given in the question? Btw, there are two important points: 1) random forest is really random model and its accuracy may change in different runs if seed didn't specified, 2) CV in caret is used just for determination of optimal tuning parameters and final model is built on the whole training dataset.

Comment: OK, if you want to compare models accuracy you might need to build models with bootstrap validation, estimate confidence interval of accuracy from each model and compare them between different models. In such a way you may estimate statistical significance of prediction accuracy of separate models. But this is a question probably for http://stats.stackexchange.com/